# Facebook Application User Count

Tags: facebook

Do any of the Facebook APIs give me the ability to get the total number of users that have allowed my application?  I see the ability to get the users that accessed it in the last day and the last month but not the current total count.  I have looked through a lot of the documentation (which is daunting to say the least) and didnt see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it via [Graph API Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/), though you have to look at the [FQL Insights information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights) to get a list of the available metrics.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_ID/insights/application_installed_users?access_token=TOKEN
```

The `access_token` you use needs to be an app access token, or a user access token for an admin of your app.